# Is there a proper way to indicate "stalemate" on your scoresheet?

Tags: notation, stalemate, scoresheet

Yesterday, after squandering a win, I played on until stalemate (actually, I offered a draw, but my opponent isn't a native English speaker, so I don't think she understood; in a few more plies we hit stalemate).

I realized I didn't know how to indicate this on my scoresheet and I just wrote "stalemate" in English.

**Question**: Is there a proper way to indicate "stalemate" on your scoresheet?

For checkmate, I believe it's usual to write #, but I'm not sure for stalemate.

Comment: There is no listed abbreviation in C.13 of the FIDE Laws. http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=171&view=article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your scoresheet you are required to record the result which 99.99% of the time will be one of 1-0, 0-1, ½-½. In the very rare cases when it is not one of those somebody will almost certainly be appealing the arbiter's / organizer's decision ;-).

You are not required to put how that result was achieved, e.g. flag dropped, resigned, defaulted, draw by 3-fold repetition, draw by 5-fold repetition, draw by 50 move rule, draw by 75 move rule (I actually got to rule that in a junior competition a few weeks ago - a real pain in the backside having to count up to 75 ;-) ), successful draw claim under appendix G in a quickplay finish that my opponent wasn't trying to win, successful draw claim under appendix G in a quickplay finish that my opponent couldn't win by normal means, checkmate, stalemate, etc. Note that I believe some national federations still allow adjudication but FIDE does not.

You get the picture! It would get a bit silly. Of course you are free to record that if you want. Just that not being a requirement there is no "approved" way for doing this.

Comment: It could be technically incorrect to record a draw as "0.5-0.5". The proper notation according to the glossary of the Laws (under "result", referencing 8.7) appears to be "½-½". See also "Points" (Article 10), where ½ is again used.

Answer (score 2):

2c:

Seems logical to use the symbol for zugzwang (no good move) and checkmate next to each other: ‡# (zugzwang is usually a circle with a dot at the centre.)

Answer (score 1):

Stalemate is so rare that it doesn't seem to have it's own notation symbol. It is not listed in the [FIDE Handbook](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article), section C.13, which is the official source on these kind of rules. Even the symbol for mate (`#`) is optional. I would just go for the word 'stalemate' like you did.